# Can I show preview pdf, doc, jpg, etc files on the view page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have attachments for my user.

Migration:

```
def change
  add_column :user, :name, :string
  add_column :user, :attachments, :string, array: true, default: []
end
```

Model:

```
has_many_attached :attachments
validates(:attachments, blob: { content_type: ['application/pdf',
                                               'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                               'application/msword',
                                               'text/plain',
                                               'image/png',
                                               'text/csv',] }
```

Controller:

```
def user_params
  params[:user][:attachments] ||= []
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, attachments: [])
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'image_processing'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'redis'
```

Attachments can have different formats: docx, pdf, jpg, etc.
And I want to show a preview of these files on my page.

UPD:

```
- if @users.attachments.attached?
  - @users.attachments.each do |attachment|
    - if attachment.previewable?  #pdf files
      = link_to image_tag(attachment.preview(resize: '200x200')), rails_blob_path(attachment, disposition: :attachment)
    - elsif attachment.variable? #picture files
      = link_to image_tag attachment.variant(resize: '200x200')
    - else
      = link_to attachment.filename, rails_blob_path(attachment, disposition: :attachment)
```

But what about docx and excel files?

Comment: https://github.com/basecamp/activestorage-office-previewer

Comment: Example to preview image in rails https://github.com/vidurpunj/RubyOnRailsActiveRecordPreviewImage for image